# save movie GraphicsMagick for r in mac

Tags: r, macos, graphics, installation, package

I am using a R 3.0.2 on a Macintosh OX Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and ran into an error trying to run this code.

Here is the link to a Genetic Algorithm: http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/  Everything works except for the last part.

I hit this error when I try to run the animation in R:

```
    > # in order to save the animation
    > library(animation)
    > saveMovie(animate_plot(), interval = 0.1, outdir = getwd())
    Error: could not find function "saveMovie"
```

This is what I tried…

```html
> library(GraphicsMagick)
Error in library(GraphicsMagick) : 
  there is no package called ‘GraphicsMagick’
> saveGIF(animate_plot(), interval = 0.1, outdir = getwd())
Error: Use 'theme' instead. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.1)
> install.packages("~/Downloads/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0.tar", repos = NULL)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘~/Downloads/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0.tar’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
Error in install.packages : file ‘~/Downloads/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-         darwin14.0.0.tar’ is not an OS X binary package
```

The code is in the link but the problem is that I cannot install GraphicsMagick in R.

I tried MacPort to download the library and download the library from a folder outside CRAN through browsing in the install packages in R.

Here is the link to the animation library: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/animation.pdf

I tried downloading these libraries off the internet: ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0.tar, ImageMagick-6.9.0, MacPorts-2.3.3-10.8-MountainLion.pkg, but they didn't work. I hope you can show me how to animate this. Thanks!

Comment: ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick or Lyx are external to R. You would not use `install.packages` for them. The maintainer of the Mac R fork, Simon Urbanek, advises against using any of fink, MacPorts or homebrew for installation of external packages.

Comment: Thanks Man. I guess it is for an older version of R or there is another method to create these cool graphics, because obviously this was done in R in the past. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't really know. The documentation says `saveMovie` should work, but I get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for editing my link. It is a shame the animation doesn't work with the latest versions of R. It doesn't really matter, because I was doing this for fun, but it is a shame that it doesn't work, because it is really cool. Hopefully, I will come across away to do these types of simulations/animations in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use saveGIF instead of saveMovie and it will work.

Comment: Give me some time to check this out. Thanks though. If you are right I will up vote you or click check. Cheers mate!!!